# Обработка нажатия F2 в дереве

Tags: java, swing

У меня есть JTree, в котором я регистрирую какие-либо горячие клавиши:

```
    tree.registerKeyboardAction(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ... 
      }
    }, keystroke, JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
```

Все горячие клавиши зарегистрировались нормально, кроме <kbd>F2</kbd>. При нажатии <kbd>F2</kbd> не происходит ничего (а должен появиться диалог). Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Компоненты хранят набор стандартных операций в inputMap и actionMap. Загружаются они лениво, т.е. при первом событии клавиатуры на компоненте. Или при обращении к ключам actionMap. Перед тем, как регистрировать новое событие мы можем явно удалить событие по умолчанию. Здесь важно помнить, что если из map можно методом get получить значение по ключу, не факт, что пара ключ-значение содержится именно в этой map. Поэтому для удаления нам необходимо пройти по всей иерархии action maps, которая есть у каждой компоненты:

```
    Object dak = tree.getInputMap().get(keystroke);
    if (dak != null) {
      ActionMap map = tree.getActionMap();
      Action act = map.get(dak);
      if (act != null) {
        while (map != null) {
          Object[] keys = map.keys();
          if (keys != null 
            && Arrays.asList(keys).contains(dak)) {
            map.remove(dak);
            return;
          }
          map = map.getParent();
        }
      }
    }

    tree.registerKeyboardAction(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      }
    }, keystroke, JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
```

На будущее, стандартные события компонентов можно найти в классе [BasicLookAndFeel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicLookAndFeel.html). Поэтому список горячих клавиш, с которыми у вас могли бы быть проблемы, гораздо шире: "ctrl C", "ctrl V", "ctrl X", "control INSERT", "shift INSERT", "shift DELETE", "shift UP", "ctrl shift UP", и так далее...

Answer (score 1):

Используйте

> `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F2")`

Comment: С KeyStroke там всё в порядке. У меня есть лист из keystroke, и все они регистрируются нормально: F3, F4, F5 и т.д. работают. А F2 - нет.

Comment: Возможно, связано с тем, что в JTree по нажатию F2 запускается редактирование имени узла. Наверно, придется поменять клавишу.

Comment: Похоже, что так. И нет способа заблокировать это событие (редактирование)?